# C# not reading files properly when using .Path class

Tags: c#, .net, directory

I'm trying to read a folder and do a look at the file names. Using this code:

```
  try
  {
    var folderPath = @"C:\Users\Gamer\source\repos\carValLocal\carValLocal\files\";

    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path.GetFileName(folderPath)))
     {
       var ha = file;
     }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
     {
       Console.WriteLine(ex);
       Console.ReadLine();
     }
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

> The path is not of a legal form

My original filepath:

```
var folderPath = @"C:\Users\Gamer\source\repos\carValLocal\carValLocal\files\";
```

To find the bad chars I wrote this bit of code:

```
string illegal = @"C:\Users\Gamer\source\repos\carValLocal\carValLocal\files\";
string invalid = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());

foreach (char c in invalid)
{
  illegal = illegal.Replace(c.ToString(), "");
}
```

which came back with:

> "CUsersGamersourcereposcarValLocalcarValLocalfiles"

Which clearly isn't a file name.

If I don't use the `Path` class, it still finds files. How can I make this work because everything I've tried (like removing illegal chars) just doesn't work.

Comment: I suppose files is a directory. So remove the \ character from the end and also Path.GetFileName(folderPath). If you want to enumerate the files from your folderPath, use `Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath)`

Comment: First debug step: what does `Path.GetFileName(folderPath)` actually return? - not "all the files in that folder"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for given folder path

```
var folderPath = @"C:\Users\Gamer\source\repos\carValLocal\carValLocal\files\";
```

The existing call

```
Path.GetFileName(folderPath);
```

returns empty string: `""` since

```
C:\Users\Gamer\source\repos\carValLocal\carValLocal\files\
\                                                        /|
 --------------------- directory ------------------------ file
```

if you want to look for files in `C:\Users\Gamer\source\repos\carValLocal\carValLocal\files` you can
use `Path.GetDirectoryName`:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(folderPath)))
{
    ...
}
```

If you want some kind of *path manipulation*, try `DirectoryInfo`, e.g. let's have a look for files in

```
  C:\Users\Gamer\source\repos\carValLocal\carValLocal
```

Code:

```
  var folderPath = @"C:\Users\Gamer\source\repos\carValLocal\carValLocal\files\";

  DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);

  foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(di.Parent.FullName)) {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles` can also be used